# How we can define routes in angularjs by a single pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As you know, in generally registering routes in angular done in `.config` function by this way:

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

        var routes = { ... /* an array which has couples of urls */ ... }

        routes.forEach(function (route) {
            $routeProvider.when(route, {
                templateUrl: route
                ,
                resolve: {
                    deps: PageResolver
                }
            });
        });
```

so by this way we map any `"#/[...]"` to `"/[...]"` in our single page, **BUT** before that, we should define all of them in config function. consider our application has too many pages which every one of them can be gotten into `ng-view` element in our main page, so it does not seems good idea to register them while there can be define with same role.

for example in our project the common role for mapping route is that every actual url will be route by `"#/"` prefix.

**My question** is that how we can define routes in angularjs by a single pattern? is there any better solution (or trick!) to do it?
thank you so much.

Comment: As I see it, you have already given the answer to your own question in the code above. You are assigning routes homogeneously through a routes array. Have I misunderstood your question? I don't see any better way to do so.

Comment: @manasisakhare consider every view which could be loaded into ng-view may have some hyperlink which we did not map them explicitly! but in my aspect if i could define a role such as "#/*" we also can include every links in route map without registering them explicitly. is it clear now what i want?

Comment: Oh. In that case, I think a $routeProvider.otherwise() would solve your issue. Right? @Ali Adl

Comment: NO!, otherwise() refers to one fixed url!

Answer (score 0):

You can give regex in the path for routes. Please check this [GitHub Doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)